# How to have a distribuited GWT application with ObjectDB and Spring?

Tags: spring, gwt, objectdb

I've been developing a GwT application as a project for my computer science faculty. 
It consists in 2 or 3 hosts running it, each of one has a client and a server and it is designed for a company renting cars which has 2 or 3 different points in a town. 
So each point of renting has got its own client/server in the same host.
The problems comes out when point A has finished the cars to rent and needs to ask for some of them to point B or point C. So GWT application of point A needs to access the remote database in hosts of point B or Point C.
As database we use Objectdb because it's very simple and efficient and we use Spring to better interface between database and application. I've learnt that with Spring it's possible to create REST services to access the other remote databases via URL...I would need some explanation on how to do it, or a simple guid.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Simply you want to make request doGet to any server and get the response data and on the other hand a request handler on the server  to handle the request and reply with data

data is handled as `JSON` object

```
Package com.google.gwt.http.client
```

is providing the whole process for you

you can explore the pacakge [here](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/http/client/package-summary.html)

and here is good [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/Xsite) from Google step by step to describe the whole process

Comment: Thank you dear! I'll have a look and let you know. thank you! :)